# Mysql user can't update temp table (has all privileges)

Tags: mysql, privileges, temporary

I try to execute the following query via php:

```
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
            AS 
            SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE vacancyid = '22207';
            UPDATE temp_table SET vacancyid='22216' WHERE vacancyid='22207';
            INSERT INTO newdatabase.vacancies SELECT * FROM temp_table;
            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
```

This gives an error:

```
Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE temp_table SET vacancyid='22216' WHERE vacancyid='22207';
```

If i execute the query directly **in PMA it works fine**.
The user I connect with in PHP has these priveliges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON firstdatabase.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdatabase.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Anyone got a clue?

PHP code:

```
            //Get the new autoincrement id of the vacancy of individual jobboard
            $iNewId = $db->lookup("SELECT vacancyid FROM ".$aBoardInfo['username'].".vacancies ORDER BY vacancyid DESC LIMIT 1");
            $iNewId = $iNewId + 1;  

            $db->query("                                
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
        AS 
        SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE vacancyid = '". $iVacancyid ."' ; 

        UPDATE temp_table SET vacancyid=". $iNewId ." WHERE vacancyid='". $iVacancyid ."' ; 

        INSERT INTO ".$aBoardInfo['username'].".vacancies SELECT * FROM temp_table ; 

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table ;   
        ");
```

Comment: Added the php code to the question.

Comment: I do not really understand. I should split the query in multiple queries? And why is it working in PMA?

Comment: yes you have to split it. I do not know how PMA executes the query.

Comment: Wow, thats the solutions indeed! Thanks alot. How do I select your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is described in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) in example 2

**Example #2 SQL Injection**

> ```
> <?php
> $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
> $res    = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1; DROP TABLE mysql.user");
> if (!$res) {
>     echo "Error executing query: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> Error executing query: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax  to use near 'DROP TABLE mysql.user' at line 1
>
> Prepared statements
>
> Use of the multiple statement with prepared statements is not
>   supported.